# Help with burning inductor in an LM2576 regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-source

I was helping a friend to design a constant 3A current source using an LM2576 to drive a load. Problem is that the 100uH inductor keeps burning every time the circuit is switched on. One option is to swap the regular inductor with a coil inductor. However, it is expensive and we cannot afford it yet.

There was this vague idea that struck about using a zener diode. I am not sure how I can implement this and is this actually practically viable?
[image: Circuit]

Comment: What's the current rating of the inductor? As the rule of thumb it should be twice as big as the supplied current.

Comment: 1. What is the relationship of the schematic to the circuit you are designing (the schematic looks like a standard buck converter with constant-voltage output, but you ask about a constant current source)? 2. What is the schematic of the actual circuit you designed? 3. What inductor part number did you use? 4. What was your idea about using a zener?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It was my friend's design. I'll get back to you. I'm a new fellow at this. Since my current requirement was 3A, as per your advice, I should be using a 6A rating. Are these kind of inductors available?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry if I sound stupid or clueless. 
1. No seperate schematic. Just the image.
From what I understand about zeners, it provides a constant current despite fluctuations in voltage. So if I connect a zener _somewhere_, I should have a constant 3A current.

Comment: @VoltAmpereWatt your understanding about Zener diodes is completely wrong. Or at least your description is. I afraid your background is insufficient to design power supplies.

Comment: `One option is to swap the regular inductor with a coil inductor.` Could explain what you mean by this? Specifically, what is a "regular inductor" vs. a "coil inductor"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you help me out?

Comment: @VoltAmpereWatt It depends on the help you need. If you can ask specific and clear questions, we can answer them. This is what this site is for. But you should have a basic background, right?

Comment: @uint128_t I don't know to describe it. The coil inductor is the one with, well, coils. Loops of conductor. The other one would be a choke, _at least that is what we call it_.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How does a zener diode work? Why is it used in regulators?

Comment: @VoltAmpereWatt, your understanding is totally backwards. A zener (operated in reverse breakdown) keeps a near-constant voltage regardless of how the current through it varies.

Comment: Also, maybe you're not understanding this: D1 in your schematic is a schottky diode, not a zener.

Comment: @VoltAmpereWatt Perhaps you are referring to a open-core inductor vs closed-core inductor? The main difference is that the closed-core producing less electromagnetic noise as the magnetic field is mostly staying inside the core.

Comment: If you want to know how a zener works, do some research (say, on this site or Wikipedia). If you still have specific questions, come back and ask a new question. But this is not a chat site, we can't just answer broad questions like "how does a zener work" in comments.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'll search for that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd probably answer that the best with a visual description. One looks like regular resistor with color bands, the other looks like a coil on a core.

Comment: Oh, with regular inductor you mean a _SMALL SIGNAL_ inductor, designed for filters at several __mA__? Can you already guess what went wrong, maybe? You're trying to push a proverbial elephant through a garden hose. Components have specifications, which are there for a reason.

Comment: @Asmyldof That is probably it. I'll get back after putting in an inductor with a higher rating.

Answer (score 5):

The chosen regulator (LM2576) is probably operating in continuous conduction mode on normal and full loads so the inductor will be seeing a peak current that might be about 20% higher than full load current. If full load current is 3A (as per the circuit in the question) then the inductor has to be able to handle 3.6 amps without too many losses.

Losses include copper resistive losses and core saturation.

> One option is to swap the regular inductor with a coil inductor.

This makes no sense because all inductors are coils. Maybe because it "looks like regular resistor with color bands" you were fooled into thinking it wasn't a "wound/coiled" device. It is.

Those "regular resistor with color bands" are unsuitable for your application. This [one](http://uk.farnell.com/bourns-jw-miller/78f151j-rc/choke-150uh-90ma-5-4-7mhz/dp/1180371): -

[image]

Is 150 uH but only rated to currents of 0.15 amps. It has very fine windings under the paint/enamel and has a dc resistance of 5.4 ohms i.e. it will fry!